# ¿How to place a vertex in the same x position as another one?

Tags: transforms

Im trying to use the vertex snap tool in order to place one vertex in the same x position as another one. Technically are in the same position but in the 3d view they are not displayed properly.

[image: Vertex displayef in User perspective]

Vertex 1:

[image: vertex 1 x position]

Vertex 2:

[image: vetex 2 x position]

In Front Orthographic mode vertices are dispalyed properly.I don't know if it is a possible bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Little unclear on why you propose they aren't displayed properly??

Comment: @batFINGER is right, they seem to be displayed properly. Just check the closest floor line. It's perfectly parallel to the selected edge.